# Relation Among Conjugacy Classes

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

*This is more a request to find out if there is any work in the literature
discussing certain things.*

Is there a naturally defined partial ordering on the set of conjugacy classes of a finite group G?  Or a graph with the classes as vertices?

Definitely the class of the identity element will be an extremal element in the partial ordering, or an isolated vertex in case a graph is defined.

Ideally a relation with some bearing on the representation of the group would be interesting.

Suppose Z is the centralizer of an element, then a relation might  make sense when defined in terms of the inner products between  of Ind$_Z^G 1_Z$ for two such centrlizers of non-conjugate elements.

Perhaps this has been studied.
Can someone point me out to any such work?